# How create a new schema and make a migration for every new user registration approved?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, multi-tenant

I'm working on a project that will be a marketplace for a shop here in my country, I already have experience for projects multitenant when is a small number of clients like 100 and we have 2 days for approval and we make a new database for that client.

But in this project, the client can't wait for 2 days and we make some tests here and Laravel takes so much time to make a migration for a newly created schema. But this job of migration we make this manually and we want to make this programmatically.

I search on the web for tutorials or examples like this but don't find it. What is the fastest way to create a schema and populate it with the databases from migration?

Can you guys show me some tutorial or an idea of how to make this automatic when the user makes a registration on our website, and automatically creates the schema and populate with new tables!

Comment: https://tenancy.dev

Comment: I see this framework but I can't use this, because my admin is an Angular project and I just use Laravel for API, so I need a custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, add your existing database in project then:-

Use package `migrations-generator`. Install it using:-

```
composer require --dev "xethron/migrations-generator"
```

Then run:-

```
php artisan migrate:generate
```

For selected tables use:-

```
php artisan migrate:generate table1,table2,table3,table4,table5
```

For ignoring selected tables:-

```
php artisan migrate:generate --ignore="table3,table4,table5"
```

It will directly create in migration folder of your project directory i.e. `database > migrations`

Comment: I don't understand very well you response i know how to make a migration what i don't know create a schema and make a fast migration for that new schema programaticaly, you understand? Thank you for you answer